# Can $(x^2+a^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ be integrated without using trigonometric substitutions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that
$$
\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx
$$
can be solved using a trigonometric substitution, but is there a trick to calculate this integral without using trigonometric substitutions? I think something in the same spirit with solving
$$
\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx
$$
by adding and subtracting $x^2$ to the numerator and then integrating by parts once one knows (and it is simple) how to integrate
$$
\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)}\,dx
$$
Any suggestion or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: None come to mind immediately, and the integral is borderline trivial with trig sub. Why would you want a solution that does *not* involve it?

Comment: The idea is that the primitive is very simple so I'm wondering if the trig subsitution is the only way to tackle this integral.

Comment: Use the Ansatz $Ax^m(x^2+a^2)^n+C$.

Comment: I do not understand the **lone vote** to close this question.

Comment: I'll mention the "$ u-$square substitution" method described by Betounes and Redfern in _The College Mathematics Journal_, vol. 48, #4, pp. 284-7 (September 2017); what **RamanujanXV** shows below is one application.  There seems to be a small rebellion developing against "trig-substitution", as I've seen a few discussions lately of alternative techniques, some of them being revivals of ones taught in the somewhat distant past.

Comment: @boojum An illuminating article! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple approach would be:-

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{(x^3)(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx$$

Substituting $(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2})$ as $t^2$,we get :

$$\int\frac{-1}{a^2t^2}dt=\frac{1}{a^2t} +c=\frac{x}{(a^2){(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}} +c  $$

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, let $a=1$

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx\\
= &\int \frac{2x^{\frac12}}{(x^2+1)^{\frac14}} 
d\left( \frac{x^{\frac12}}{(x^2+1)^{\frac14}}\right)
= \left( \frac{x^{\frac12}}{(x^2+1)^{\frac14}}\right)^2
= \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^{\frac12}}
\end{align}

Comment: I think power 1/4 at the beginning of the second line in the denominator should be 1/2.

Comment: @Quanto The final result is wrong .It should be $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @RamanujanXV - you’re right; corrected